# Want to show images information from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP, I want to get image information from database when I click on a specific image.

This is the code I'm using, could you help me out?

Code:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $select_db = mysql_select_db("fashion",$connection);
    $winter = mysql_query("Select * from winter",$connection);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($winter))
    {
        echo "<img  src=\"winter images/" . $row['image_name']. "\" width=\"200\" //height=\"293\"/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated.Use pdo or mysqli_* functions

Answer (score 0):

Since mysql_fetch_array only pulls regular array, replace it with mysql_fetch_assoc. This should work !!

```
  <?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $select_db = mysql_select_db("fashion",$connection);
    $winter = mysql_query("Select * from winter",$connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($winter)){
    echo '<img  src= "folder/'.$row["image_name"].'" width="200" height="293">';         
    }

  ?>
```

Since mysql is deprecated, try using [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/book.pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `echo $row['image_name'];` to see whether you are getting the image name or not. If you are getting it properly then try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($winter))
    {
$imagePath='winter/'.$row['image_name'];
        echo '<img src="'.$imagePath.'" width="200" height="293" >';
    }
```

**1.** Why are you messing up so much with the image tag in your echo statement. if you put double quotes inside the single quotes then also it will work.
**2. **Please stop using **mysql_*** as it was deprecated before it was deprecated.